# grub2 and windows in UEFI mode woes

Tags: linux, fedora, windows-10, grub2

My `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` reads:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  chainloader +1 
}
```

Yet when I try to boot windows 10, I get an error stating that the path to EFI is wrong. The relevant windows drive install is:

```
Disk /dev/sde: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe55015e8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sde1            2048 975849471 975847424 465.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sde2       975849472 976771071    921600   450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

Which does not appear to be UEFI enabled which is odd but whatever.

**How can I get grub2 to actually load Windows 10?**

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120233/10526), I tried:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod search_fs_uuid
  insmod ntfs
  insmod chain
  search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd4,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd4,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci4,msdos1 343419363418FC94
  chainloader (${root})/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
  boot
}
```

I kept getting `ntfs.mod not found` errors for all the `insmod` commands so tried to remove them. Still, nothing.

Comment: Apparently you installed fedora/grub in UEFI mode and while you installed your Windows in CSM/legacy mode. And you can't boot BIOS version of Windows Boot Manager with grub EFI. You'll either need to reinstall fedora/grub in CSM/legacy mode, or install a set of UEFI version of Windows Boot Manager to an EFI System Partition with `bcdboot` in Windows, then have grub EFI chainload it. I don't know why you get those module not mound error though.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you installed fedora/grub in UEFI mode and while you installed your Windows in CSM/legacy mode. And you can't boot BIOS version of Windows Boot Manager with grub EFI. You'll either need to reinstall fedora/grub in CSM/legacy mode, or install a set of UEFI version of Windows Boot Manager to an EFI System Partition with `bcdboot` in Windows, then have grub EFI chainload it.

If you want a UEFI bootloader that is capable of legacy boot, refind is probably what you are looking for: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/features.html

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 24 hours. Just in case someone has some magic we are unaware of... Hope springs eternal and all that. ^_~

Comment: See my edited answer for a possible magic your might be looking for.